# How do I pass -mfpmath=sse to LLVM using CLANG

Tags: macos, clang, llvm

I am trying to compile a number of GNU tools on Mac OS X [10.8.5].  One of the optimization options I was able to use in the past is '-mfpmath=sse', but now I get the message:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpmath=sse'
```

Now, llvm-gcc help says it supports '-mfpmath=sse', and clang has a method of passing things to llvm using '-mllvm ', but I cannot seem to make them work together.

Are these two options even meant to work together?  If so, how?

What if I want to pass multiple LLVM arguments from CLANG using '-mllvm '?  Is that possible, and if so, how?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 2):

You do not need this flag with clang. It defaults to "-mfpmath=sse" as soon as your processor does support it.

If you need to pass multiple options to LLVM directly (though, it seems to be pretty bad idea - you do not need to do so), you can just -mllvm multiple times, e.g. "-mllvm -foo -mllvm -bar".